# How can I check if a radio button is selected in Jetpack Compose UI tests?

Tags: android, kotlin, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

Does anybody know how to check, which radio button is selected in Android UI tests for Jetpack Compose created UI?

I made a radio button group via the attached code, but I don't know how to identify which one is selected by the UI tests.

```
Column(Modifier.selectableGroup()) {....}
```

Is there some kind of assertion that returns the selected radio button of the radio button group?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the onClick property of the RadioButton to some callback provide an id to identify what button is selected:

```
@Composable
fun MyRadioButton(
   onClick: (id) -> Unit
) {
    RadioButton(
        onClick = {
            onClick("myRadioButtonId")
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I have made it to tag each radio button, but I don't know how to retrieve which one is selected on tests which one is selected. If I use an if statement e.g.  if(radioButton1.assertIsSelected()) I will get a semantic node interaction instead of a Boolean value.. How can I check on tests which of those is selected?

Comment: You should be calling a viewmodel to determine the state of your radio buttons and not the UI elements themselves. So in the code sample I provided, set the state in your viewmodel when onClick is called and have your UI test retrieve the state from the viewmodel.